# Using numbers from new commands in ifnum

Tags: conditionals

I am trying to create a Latex document in which I define a list of items (e.g. fruits) at the beginning in order to change the resulting text / appearance of the document depending of the amount of items I have defined.

Therefore I defined a `\newcommand{\length}` which is supposed to count the number of items (fruits) and 'return' the number.

This minimal (non-)working example should illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{numlength}%
\newcommand{\length}[1]{%
    \setcounter{numlength}{0}%
    \@for\element:=#1\do{\stepcounter{numlength}}%
    \value{numlength}% Variant 1
    % \arabic{numlength}% Variant 2
    % \thenumlength% Variant 3
}
\makeatother
\def\fruits{apple,banana,mango}
\begin{document}
\section{Fruits}
Number of fruits: \length{\fruits}
\\There \ifnum\length{\fruits}=1 is just a single fruit\else are multiple fruits\fi on my list:
\\\fruits
\end{document}
```

Printing the number in my text (`Number of fruits: \length{\fruits}`) only works with variant 2 and 3 (which I understand) but using the number in the `\ifnum` doesn't work no matter which variant I use.

To be clear: I am not interested in a nice way of printing the items (fruits) themselves; my main concern is using the number I 'calculate' in my `\newcommand{\length}` in an `\ifnum` condition.

Furthermore, if possible, I would like to refrain from using any packages (`\usepackage`).

Please let me know if you need more information and thank you in advance!

Comment: `\ifnum` requires something that expands to a number, your version makes multiple assignments so is not expandable, you can not do `\ifnum\def\foo{2}\foo=2`  you have to do `\def\foo{2}\ifnum\foo=2`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_new_eq:NN \length \clist_count:N\ExplSyntaxOff` in your preamble, then your `\length\fruits` works as you want it to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle points out in his comment, in TeX you need to be expandable if you want to use your macro where TeX expects a number, hence you can't use assignments.

You have two possibilities to fix your problem:

1. Do the assignments in a first step, and use the result for your `\ifnum`.
2. Count the number of fruits with an expandable function.

The following does the latter by using a function/macro from L3:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_count:n { V }
\cs_new_eq:NN \length \clist_count:V
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\fruits{apple,banana,mango}

\begin{document}
\section{Fruits}
Number of fruits: \length{\fruits}
\\There \ifnum\length{\fruits}=1 is just a single fruit\else are multiple fruits\fi on my list:
\\\fruits
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

TeXnical information, you might want to ignore this and simply use the above:

Unlike my comment, the code in this answer uses a `V` variant, since your `\fruit` isn't set with one of the  `clist`-functions of L3, this should be semantically cleaner, since `V` will do the sanitising steps necessary for correct results, unlike `N`.

---

On the first approach:

For the first approach to work you don't need to alter all that much from your actual code. You just need to remove the direct output, and instead in a second step use the value of your `numlength` counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{numlength}%
\newcommand{\length}[1]{%
    \setcounter{numlength}{0}%
    \@for\element:=#1\do{\stepcounter{numlength}}%
}
\makeatother
\def\fruits{apple,banana,mango}
\begin{document}
\section{Fruits}
Number of fruits: \length{\fruits}\arabic{numlength}
\\There \length\fruits\ifnum\value{numlength}=1 is just a single fruit\else are multiple fruits\fi on my list:
\\\fruits
\end{document}
```

(output like above)

Comment: Thank you so much, the code you provided works like a charm and I will most definitely be using the latter approach. However, I would like to understand the first approach as well. I have tried doing that using `\edef\fruitamount{\length{\fruits}}` with all 3 variants but none of them worked. Could you elaborate on how to do it properly, please?

Comment: @Lennart See my edit for an unexpandable version. Your `\edef` has the same issue, it'd need `\length` to be fully expandable, which it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

As others have already explained, you first have to store the length in a macro and then use `\ifnum`. But the method is cumbersome and not expandable itself.

I suggest a method that doesn't require `\def`, so you don't risk to clobber existing commands (and to “invent” new ones).

You can also append to lists and do more complex branching based on the number of elements. Lists are supposed to be nonempty.

Note that `\branchonlist` is fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_lennart_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_lennart_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\appendtolist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_put_right:cn { l_lennart_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\listlength}{m}
 {
  \clist_count:c { l_lennart_list_#1_clist }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\branchonlist}{mmm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = cases, #3 = no match
  \int_case:nnF { \clist_count:c { l_lennart_list_#1_clist } } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelist{fruits}{apple,mango,banana}
\definelist{animals}{gnu,gnat}
\definelist{letters}{a}

\begin{document}

Number of fruits: \listlength{fruits}

\branchonlist{fruits}{
  {1}{There is just a single fruit}
}{There are multiple fruits}

\bigskip

Number of animals: \listlength{animals}

\branchonlist{animals}{
  {1}{There is just a single animal}
  {2}{There are two animals}
}{There are multiple animals}

\bigskip

Number of letters: \listlength{letters}

\branchonlist{letters}{
  {1}{There is just a single letter}
  {2}{There are two letters}
  {3}{There are three letters}
}{There are multiple letters}

\bigskip

\appendtolist{letters}{b}

Number of letters: \listlength{letters}

\branchonlist{letters}{
  {1}{There is just a single letter}
  {2}{There are two letters}
  {3}{There are three letters}
}{There are multiple letters}

\bigskip

\appendtolist{letters}{c}

Number of letters: \listlength{letters}

\branchonlist{letters}{
  {1}{There is just a single letter}
  {2}{There are two letters}
  {3}{There are three letters}
}{There are multiple letters}

\bigskip

\appendtolist{letters}{d}

Number of letters: \listlength{letters}

\branchonlist{letters}{
  {1}{There is just a single letter}
  {2}{There are two letters}
  {3}{There are three letters}
}{There are multiple letters}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very interesting approach which I am definetely going to use in the future whenever I'd like to use lists that need items to be appended mid-document.